# Birational morphisms from smooth variety to normal are iso in codim 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a birational surjective morphism. Let us also suppose that $Y$ is normal and $X$ is smooth. Is it true that $\pi$ becomes the isomorphism after restricting on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ for some $U \subset Y$ such that $\operatorname{codim}(Y \backslash U) \geq 2$?

Comment: Yes. Since $\operatorname{Sing}(Y) $  has codimension $\geq 2$, you can take it out and assume that $Y$ is smooth. Then you can apply Van der Waerden purity theorem (EGA IV.21.12.12); the proof is  much easier in your case but I have no time to look for a referene.

Comment: Or you can use Zariski's Main Theorem. That implies that if $\pi$ is not an isomorphism over $y\in Y$, then $\dim \pi^{-1}(y)>0$, so the locus where it is not an isomorphism can have dimension at most $\dim Y-2$.